# How to link between pages in a Sphinx doc set

Tags: python-sphinx, cross-reference

I can't find the answer after much Googling.

I am making my first foray into sphinx, and I can't see how to include links to another page within my sphinx docs. It seems that the `:doc` directive should do the trick, but it isn't working.

For example, imagine I have the very simple tree:

```
./index.rst
./files/CPPFiles.rst
./files/PythonFiles.rst
```

The first one, `index.rst` as well as having a TOC wants a link to one of these subfiles in the "free" text, so my index.rst contains this:

```
My Docs
=======

This is a Python module but powered by a C++ back end. 
Unless you're planning on extending this module you only need
to read :doc:`the Python docs<files/PythonFiles>`.


.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   files/PythonFiles
   files/CPPFiles
```

I've also tried with just

```
:doc`files/PythonFiles`
```

In both cases, the text within the `:doc:` appears as expected, but is not a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White space has meaning in reStructuredText.

```
:doc:`the Python docs<files/PythonFiles>`.
```

Should be:

```
:doc:`the Python docs <files/PythonFiles>`.
```